# How to reliably get dependent variable name from formula object?

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following formula:

```
myformula<-formula("depVar ~ Var1 + Var2")
```

How to reliably get dependent variable name from formula object?

I failed to find any built-in function that serves this purpose.
I know that `as.character(myformula)[[2]]` works, as do

```
sub("^(\\w*)\\s~\\s.*$","\\1",deparse(myform))
```

It just seems to me, that these methods are more a hackery, than a reliable and standard method to do it.

---

Does anyone know perchance what exactly method the e.g. `lm` use? I've seen it's code, but it is a little to cryptic to me... here is a quote for your convenience:

```
    > lm
function (formula, data, subset, weights, na.action, method = "qr", 
    model = TRUE, x = FALSE, y = FALSE, qr = TRUE, singular.ok = TRUE, 
    contrasts = NULL, offset, ...) 
{
    ret.x <- x
    ret.y <- y
    cl <- match.call()
    mf <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
    m <- match(c("formula", "data", "subset", "weights", "na.action", 
        "offset"), names(mf), 0L)
    mf <- mf[c(1L, m)]
    mf$drop.unused.levels <- TRUE
    mf[[1L]] <- as.name("model.frame")
    mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame())
    if (method == "model.frame") 
        return(mf)
    else if (method != "qr") 
        warning(gettextf("method = '%s' is not supported. Using 'qr'", 
            method), domain = NA)
    mt <- attr(mf, "terms")
    y <- model.response(mf, "numeric")
    w <- as.vector(model.weights(mf))
    if (!is.null(w) && !is.numeric(w)) 
        stop("'weights' must be a numeric vector")
    offset <- as.vector(model.offset(mf))
    if (!is.null(offset)) {
        if (length(offset) != NROW(y)) 
            stop(gettextf("number of offsets is %d, should equal %d (number of observations)", 
                length(offset), NROW(y)), domain = NA)
    }
    if (is.empty.model(mt)) {
        x <- NULL
        z <- list(coefficients = if (is.matrix(y)) matrix(, 0, 
            3) else numeric(), residuals = y, fitted.values = 0 * 
            y, weights = w, rank = 0L, df.residual = if (!is.null(w)) sum(w != 
            0) else if (is.matrix(y)) nrow(y) else length(y))
        if (!is.null(offset)) {
            z$fitted.values <- offset
            z$residuals <- y - offset
        }
    }
    else {
        x <- model.matrix(mt, mf, contrasts)
        z <- if (is.null(w)) 
            lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, 
                ...)
        else lm.wfit(x, y, w, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, 
            ...)
    }
    class(z) <- c(if (is.matrix(y)) "mlm", "lm")
    z$na.action <- attr(mf, "na.action")
    z$offset <- offset
    z$contrasts <- attr(x, "contrasts")
    z$xlevels <- .getXlevels(mt, mf)
    z$call <- cl
    z$terms <- mt
    if (model) 
        z$model <- mf
    if (ret.x) 
        z$x <- x
    if (ret.y) 
        z$y <- y
    if (!qr) 
        z$qr <- NULL
    z
}
```

Comment: Do you only have the formula or do you have a fitted model or written code that uses the standard non-standard evaluation rules for these formula interfaces? R uses the `terms` component for this sort of think ususally

Comment: @Gavin No. I have a formula *before* calculating the model. I'm writing a function for bootstrapping that will replace the dependent variable in data.frame with given residuals. The only place from where I can get the name of dep. variable is the formula object. It will be awful waste of time if I'd fit the model just to use the $terms component.

Comment: OK, and I just remembered that `terms()` works on a formula too but dealing with that object will also be hacky and a pain. I think `as.character(myformula)[[2]]` is the least hacky - the ordering won't change any time soon I would venture.

Comment: Re you edit; that was what I was getting at. `lm` uses the standard non-standard evaluation idiom to match a formula with a data frame object. You need a `data` argument at least plus some other and then it is quite easy to get the model frame and from that the response.

Comment: See this [document](http://developer.r-project.org/nonstandard-eval.pdf) (PDF) which explains what is done in `lm()`

Comment: This does beg the question of whether you really want the name of the response variable or the response variable itself? I have added a second answer which tackles the point raised by the edit to your question and shows how to use the nonstandard evaluation idiom to extract the response variable data instead of the name.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try using `all.vars`:

```
all.vars(myformula)[1]
```

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure that the dependent variable will always be in the first position in the vector `all.vars(myformula)`?

Comment: You'd have to study the C code to determine that. The order is not documented to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: +1 No more "hacky" than `as.character(formula)[[2]]` and probably the most reliable without resorting to other, more lengthy manipulations.

Comment: Not entirely sure, I have to admit, but I think it shows the terms in order.

Comment: This variant does not depend on the order in which `all.vars` variables are returned: `all.vars(update(myformula, . ~ 1))` .

Comment: No need for updating the formula: `all.vars(myformula[[2]])` works just fine.

Comment: Please note that `all.vars(~b+c)` will give you incorrect result.

Comment: Please note that `all.vars(log(y) ~ x)[1]` will return `"y"` instead of `"log(y)"`

Comment: this is still problematic with a multivariate design

Comment: Downvote because the solution is not reliable as Tim and luke.sonnet pointed out, see TPArrow's result below

Answer (score 14):

I suppose you could also cook your own function to work with `terms()`:

```
getResponse <- function(formula) {
    tt <- terms(formula)
    vars <- as.character(attr(tt, "variables"))[-1] ## [1] is the list call
    response <- attr(tt, "response") # index of response var
    vars[response] 
}

R> myformula <- formula("depVar ~ Var1 + Var2")
R> getResponse(myformula)
[1] "depVar"
```

It is just as hacky as `as.character(myformyula)[[2]]` but you have the assurance that you get the correct variable as the ordering of the call parse tree isn't going to change any time soon.

This isn't so good with multiple dependent variables:

```
R> myformula <- formula("depVar1 + depVar2 ~ Var1 + Var2")
R> getResponse(myformula)
[1] "depVar1 + depVar2"
```

as they'll need further processing.

Answer (score 13):

I found an useful package 'formula.tools' which is suitable for your task.

code Example:

> f <- as.formula(a1 + a2~a3 + a4)
>
> lhs.vars(f)  #get dependent variables

[1] "a1" "a2"

> rhs.vars(f)  #get independent variables

[1] "a3" "a4"

Answer (score 6):

Based on your edit to get the actual response, not just its name, we can use the nonstandard evaluation idiom employed by `lm()` and most other modelling functions with a formula interface in base R

```
form <- formula("depVar ~ Var1 + Var2")
dat <- data.frame(depVar = rnorm(10), Var1 = rnorm(10), Var2 = rnorm(10))

getResponse <- function(form, data) {
    mf <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
    m <- match(c("formula", "data"), names(mf), 0L)
    mf <- mf[c(1L, m)]
    mf$drop.unused.levels <- TRUE
    mf[[1L]] <- as.name("model.frame")
    mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame())
    y <- model.response(mf, "numeric")
    y
} 

> getResponse(form, dat)
          1           2           3           4           5 
-0.02828573 -0.41157817  2.45489291  1.39035938 -0.31267835 
          6           7           8           9          10 
-0.39945771 -0.09141438  0.81826105  0.37448482 -0.55732976
```

As you see, this gets the actual response variable data from the supplied data frame.

How this works is that the function first captures the function call without expanding the `...` argument as that contains things not needed for the evaluation of the data for the formula.

Next, the `"formula"` and `"data"` arguments are matched with the call. The line `mf[c(1L, m)]` selects the function name from the call (`1L`) and the locations of the two matched arguments. The `drop.unused.levels` argument of `model.frame()` is set to `TRUE` in the next line, and then the call is updated to switch the function name in the call from `lm` to `model.frame`. All the above code does is takes the call to `lm()` and processes that call into a call to the `model.frame()` function.

This modified call is then evaluated in the parent environment of the function - which in this case is the global environment.

The last line uses the `model.response()` extractor function to take the response variable from the model frame.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know about the `model.frame` functionality. Although it offers a little different paradigm (need to supply the actual data.frame), I believe it should be the most versatile and trustworthy solution, especially when I only work with `glm` models. I feel I need to dig more into this idiom. And thank you for "nonstandard-eval.pdf".

Comment: Can you tell me, how approximately speed of this method compares with the other (little more "hacky") ones? - I believe I'll need to use this functionality inside a bootstrap loop so speed is also a concern for me.

Comment: Benchmark it yourself in your use-case. I doubt it will be quicker than than `foo <- as.character(form)[[2]]` followed by `resp <- data[ , foo]`, but it *is* the way R Core have chosen to identify the data reliably for a model represented by a formula. Depending on what you are doing in your application, you might not need the extra formula functionality handling/generality that the `model.frame` idiom.

Answer (score 2):

This should always give you all dependent vars:

```
myformula<-formula("depVar1 + depVar2 ~ Var1 + Var2")
as.character(myformula[[2]])[-1]
#[1] "depVar1" "depVar2"
```

And I wouldn't consider this particularly "hacky".

**Edit:**

Something strange happens with 3 dependents:

```
myformula<-formula("depVar1 + depVar2 + depVar3 ~ Var1 + Var2")
as.character(myformula[[2]])
#[1] "+"                 "depVar1 + depVar2" "depVar3"
```

So this might not be as reliable as I thought.

**Edit2:**

Okay, `myformula[[2]]` is a language object and `as.character` seems to do something similar as `languageEl`.

```
length(myformula[[2]])
#[1] 3
languageEl(myformula[[2]],which=1)
#`+`
languageEl(myformula[[2]],which=2)
#depVar1 + depVar2
languageEl(myformula[[2]],which=3)
#depVar3
languageEl(languageEl(myformula[[2]],which=2),which=2)
#depVar1
```

If you check the length of each element, you could create your own extraction function. But this is probably too much of a hack.

**Edit3:**
Based on the answer by @seancarmody `all.vars(myformula[[2]])` is the way to go.

Comment: `getFormulaVars = function(x,dependent=TRUE) {
  if(class(x) != 'formula') stop("x argument must be a formula",call.=FALSE)
  all.vars(x[[if(dependent) 3 else 2]])
}`

Answer (score 2):

Using `all.vars` is very tricky as it won't detect the response from a one-sided formula. For example

```
all.vars(~x+1)
[1] "x"
```

that is wrong.

Here is the most reliable way of getting the response:

```
    getResponseFromFormula = function(formula) {
        if (attr(terms(as.formula(formula))    , which = 'response'))
            all.vars(formula)[1]
        else
            NULL
    }


getResponseFromFormula(~x+1)
NULL

 getResponseFromFormula(y~x+1)
[1] "y"
```

Note that you can replace `all.vars(formula)[1]` in the function with `formula[2]` if the formula contains more than one variable for the response.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if our formula is `y ~ .`, i.e. *predict y by all other variables*. See `getResponseFromFormula(y ~ .)`

Comment: The formula you discribe is data driven. Not sure but probably all other methods wont work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite old, but I thought I'd add a base R answer which doesn't require indexing, doesn't depend on the order of the variables listed in a call to `all.vars`, and which gives the response variables as separate elements when there is more than one:

```
myformula <- formula("depVar1 + depVar2 ~ Var1 + Var2")
all_vars <- all.vars(myformula)
response <- all_vars[!(all_vars %in% labels(terms(myformula)))]

> response
[1] "depVar1" "depVar2"
```

Comment: Note that if any functions are included in the formula this method will throw errors. This is because terms(myformula) includes the functions in the formula elements, whereas all.vars() does not. The %in% call fails as it cannot match appropriately. For example, the formula "dv1 + dv2 ~ v1 + v2 + log(v3)" will incorrectly yield a response vector of dv1, dv2, *and* v3, because all.vars labels v3 as v3, while terms labels v3 as log(v3).