# Recursively editing a list in R

Tags: r, recursion, formula

In my program, I am recursively going over a nested list and adding elements to an overall list that I will return. There are a few details to be taken care of, so I can't just use `unlist`.

`formulaPart` is taken to be a [formula object](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html).

My code is:

```
parseVariables <- function(formulaPart, myList){
     for(currentVar in as.list(formulaPart))
       if(typeof(currentVar == 'language'
         parseVariables(currentVar, myList)
       else
         if(! toString(currentVar) %in% c(\\various characters)
           list <- c(list, currentVar)
    }
```

I have checked that the function correctly adds elements to the list when it should. The problem is that the list loses elements due to recursion. The elements added during one inner recursive call are not saved for another recursive call.

If this was in C++, I could just use a pointer; the same for Java. However, I do not understand how to handle this error in R.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data to work with?

Comment: Well, you're not saving the result from the inner call to `parseVariables`. Try changing `parseVariables(currentVar, myList)` to `result <- parseVariables(currentVar, myList)` and `list <- c(list, currentVar)` to `list <- c(result, currentVar)`. And you should also add a final line for the function result, which is not very clear in the form above.

Comment: I tried that and it says that `object 'result' not found`. If I save the inner call of `parseVariables` to result, how is `list <- c(result, currentVar)` going to be able to use that. They are in different branches of an if-else statement.

Comment: @Matthew, just about any formula will do. The idea is that it the function adds all elements in a formula that are not purely symbolic to a list. For example, if `formula = y ~ x + z` then the list should contain 3 new elements - `y, x, z`. The omitted various characters are those that are standard symbols, e.g. `'+', '-', ':'`

Comment: What the other commenters (and myself) are struggling with here is that this question feels like we're being shown a little snippet of some larger task, and it's hard to diagnose the problem and suggest solutions unless we have a complete, reproducible example that we can run ourselves.

Comment: @JonClaus, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217322/how-to-reliably-get-dependent-variable-name-from-formula-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R does something like pass-by-value, so you can't modify (most) existing objects just by passing them into a function. If you want to add on to something recursively, one trick would be to use an environment instead, which get passed by reference. This can easily be coerced to list when you're done.

```
parseVariables <- function(formulaPart, myList){
     for(currentVar in as.list(formulaPart)) {
       if(typeof(currentVar) == 'language') {
         parseVariables(currentVar, myList)
       }
       else {
         if(! toString(currentVar) %in% c(':', '+', '~'))
           assign(toString(currentVar), currentVar, myList)
        }
    }
}

f1 <- z ~ a:b + x
f2 <- z ~ x + y

myList <- new.env()

parseVariables(f1, myList)
parseVariables(f2, mylist)
ls(myList)
# [1] "a" "b" "x" "z"
as.list(myList)
# $x
# x
# 
# $z
# z
# 
# $a
# a
# 
# $b
# b
```

Comment: Thanks. Passing by reference is exactly what I needed.